# Python emission window length parser

Tags: python, parsing

### Background:

I am working on the paper "Firefly-inspired Heartbeat Synchronization in Overlay Networks". This paper intends, as its title suggests, to synchronize devices like fireflies synchronize when they emit light.

To do so, I implemented the adaptive Ermentrout model presented in the paper, and I ran some tests, to analyze the behaviour of the model. I currently have plots that look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD9Es.png), that show the synchronization of the nodes.

What I would like to do now is calculate the **emission window length** as a function of the time. An **emission** is defined as a collection of flash events, potentially occurring at different nodes (understand the columns in the plot). In other words, I would like to get the time from the first flash of an emission, and the time of the last flash of an emission.
This is where I have troubles, and I did not manage to solve it.

There is a parameter, $\Delta$, which is the cycle length, and this parameter can vary through time.

I started to write a parser in Python, this is what I have for now:

```
import getopt
import sys
import re


def get_time(line):
    time = re.match('(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+) \(\d+\)  \w+', line)
    return int(time.group(1)) * 3600 + int(time.group(2)) * 60 + int(time.group(3)) + int(time.group(4)) / 10 ** (len(time.group(4)))


def init_parser():
    input_file = ''
    output_file = ''

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hi:o:', ['ifile=', 'ofile='])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print('python3 Parser-emission-window.py -i <input file> -o <output file>')
        sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print('python3 Parser-emission-window.py -i <input file> -o <output file>')
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ('-i', '--ifile'):
            input_file = arg
        elif opt in ('-o', '--ofile'):
            output_file = arg

    return input_file, output_file


def parser():
    input_file, output_file = init_parser()
    reference_time, initial_time, current_time, delta = 0, 0, 0, 2
    is_reference_time, is_initial_time = False, False
    input_file = open(input_file, 'r')
    output_file = open(output_file, 'w')

    for line in input_file:
        current_line = re.match('(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d)\d* \(\d+\)  Node (\d+) emitted a flash.', line)

        if current_line and not is_initial_time:
            initial_time = get_time(line)
            is_initial_time = True

        if current_line and not is_reference_time:
            reference_time = get_time(line)
            is_reference_time = True

        if current_line and get_time(line) - reference_time < delta:
            current_time = get_time(line)
        elif current_line and get_time(line) - reference_time >= delta:
            output_file.write(str(current_time - initial_time) + "\t" + str(current_time - reference_time) + "\n")
            reference_time = get_time(line)

    input_file.close()
    output_file.close()


def main():
    parser()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But as you can see
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/katr2.png), this is not really corresponding to the other plot.

If that can be of any help, I work on Mac OSX 10.10.5.

Also if you need the corresponding log, I'll post it in the commments (can't put more than 2 links)

Any help/tip is welcomed.

Comment: [Link to log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwk2D5wlQdxudGkyaDhHQVBGU1U/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out how to do this. 
I will just post the code below, it is (I hope) enough commented if someone ever needs it. (Note that I did not take time to optimize it, and I am not a Python specialist, so some stuff I did may be incorrect/badly implemented).

```
import getopt
import re
import sys


class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self, input_file):
        self.input_file = input_file

    def get_number_of_nodes(self):
        """
        :return: the number of nodes according to the name of the file
        """
        return int(re.match('Logs/Firefly-\w\w-(\d+).+', self.input_file).group(1))

    @staticmethod
    def get_time(line):
        """
        Function get_time
        :param line: line of the log containing a timestamp of the form HH:MM:SS.NNNN
        :return: Time in seconds
        """
        time = re.match('(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+) \(\d+\)  \w+', line)
        return int(time.group(1)) * 3600 + int(time.group(2)) * 60 + int(time.group(3)) + int(time.group(4)) / 10 ** (
            len(time.group(4)))

    def get_initial_time_and_id(self):
        """
        Function get_initial_time: reads input_file until it finds the first flash
        :rtype: object
        :return: time (in seconds) of the first flash
        """
        with open(self.input_file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                current_line = re.match('(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\.\d+ \(\d+\)  Node (\d+) emitted a flash.', line)
                if current_line:
                    return self.get_time(line), int(current_line.group(4))

    # Need to define the thing to create all the tables and stuff
    def get_timestamps(self):
        """
        get_timestamps: reads the input_file (log) and every time a node emits a flash, the time at which the flash was
                        emitted is stored in the i-th array of lists_time (where i is the id of the node).
        :return: the lists containing the time at which nodes emitted light.
        """
        init_time, _ = self.get_initial_time_and_id()
        lists_time = [[] for i in range(self.get_number_of_nodes())]
        with open(self.input_file, 'r') as ifile:
            for line in ifile:
                current_line = re.match('(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d)\d* \(\d+\)  Node (\d+) emitted a flash.', line)
                if current_line:
                    lists_time[int(current_line.group(5)) - 1].append(self.get_time(line) - init_time)
        return lists_time


def get_paths():
    """
    Generate the output files by getting the input file (passed as an argument)
    :return: input file, output file for cycle lengths, output file for emission window length
    """
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hi:', ['ifile='])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print('python3 Parser-synchronization.py -i <input file>')
        sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print('python3 Parser-synchronization.py -i <input file>')
            print('Ex: \"python3 Parser-synchronization.py -i foo\" will get the file Logs/foo.txt')
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ('-i', '--ifile'):
            input_file = 'Logs/' + str(arg) + '.txt'
            output_file_cl = 'Parsed-logs/' + str(arg) + '-cl-parsed.txt'
            output_file_ewl = 'Parsed-logs/' + str(arg) + '-ewl-parsed.txt'

    return input_file, output_file_cl, output_file_ewl


def cycle_lengths(lists, ofile):
    """
    This function calculates the cycle lengths for each nodes.
    :param lists: list containing the times at which every node flashed
    :param ofile: output file to write the cycle lengths to.
    """
    with open(ofile, 'w') as output_file:
        for elem in lists:
            for i in range(1, len(elem)):
                output_file.write(str(elem[i]) + '\t' + str(elem[i] - elem[i - 1]) + '\n')


def get_closests(lists, time):
    # This is not the best thing to do, but radius = Delta/2
    # I did not want to create another parameter, especially that I only used Delta = 5 in my test.
    """
    This is the second step of the algorithm described in emission_window_length.
    It reads every time list (for each node) until it finds a timestamp within 2.5sec
    :param lists: list containing the times at which every node flashed
    :param time: time of the reference node to look for
    :return: list of all the time within 2.5 sec of the ref time (at most one per node)
    """
    radius = 2.5
    closests = []
    for l in lists:
        i = 0
        while i < len(l)-1 and abs(l[i] - time) > radius:
            i += 1
        # Now we found an element in the ball of center time and radius 2.5.
        # We need to check which of this element or the successor is closest to time.
        if abs(l[i] - time) <= radius:
            if i < len(l) - 2 and abs(l[i] - time) > abs(l[i + 1] - time):
                closests.append(l[i + 1])
            else:
                closests.append(l[i])
    return closests


def emission_window_length(lists, ofile, ref_id):
    """
    Explanation of how the function works:
      1. We get the id of the node that emitted the first flash. This will be our ref_id (passed in parameter)
      2. Every time this node emit a flash, we look for all the nodes that emitted a flash less than 2.5 seconds
         before or after the node. We consider that it is in the same emission.

      node id      node 3 = ref node, At first node 2 is not in the emission window.
         ^      -----------
         |   3  |    o     |        o              o
         |      |<-- 5 --->|
         |   2  |          |       o               o
         |      |<2.5>     |
         |   1  |     o    |         o             o
         |      -----------
         --------------------------------------------------------> time

      3. Once we have this list, we look for the min and max, and max-min is our emission window length for the
         current emission.
      4. Do this for every time ref_id flashed.
    WARNING: As the nodes do not start at the same time, we do NOT consider the flashes after ref_id node stops.
    :param lists: list containing the times at which every node flashed
    :param ofile: output file
    :param ref_id: reference id of the node that first flashed
    """
    with open(ofile, 'w') as output_file:
        for time in lists[ref_id]:
            lists_closests = get_closests(lists, time)
            # to get min and max of list, we use the built in functions in python
            min_time = min(lists_closests)
            max_time = max(lists_closests)
            length = max_time - min_time
            output_file.write('{0}\t{1}\n'.format(str(time), str(length)))


def main():
    ifile, ofile_cl, ofile_ewl = get_paths()

    parser = Parser(ifile)

    _, init_id = parser.get_initial_time_and_id()

    lists_time = parser.get_timestamps()

    cycle_lengths(lists_time, ofile_cl)

    emission_window_length(lists_time, ofile_ewl, init_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oEVC.png)